# Label in the table's cell

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview, uilabel

I want to add a label into the table's cell. In my case the cell is generated from another file using UITableViewCell . any guidance ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your other file is a subclass of UITableViewCell you can:

1. define the UITableViewCell view programmatically
2. define the view using a NIBfile

You would typically pass a pointer to the content of your table view cell to the cell init method so the cell can initialize itself with proper model information.

You should also typically retrieve the cell content view size to place your elements programmatically if you choose method 1.

Good luck.

Comment: ya I have defined the UITableViewCell view programmatically.

Comment: @maulik. Then simply call the init method on your custom table view cell whenever you create a new cell (when dequeue fails). And be sure to have the proper accessor on your cell for your model data. I also know there is something in the Apple developper site which goes over this.